# Criar botões dinamicamente

Tags: android, button, grid

Estou fazendo uma tela onde cadastro alguns usuários. Nessa tela, tenho um `ScrollView` com um `Gridlayout` dentro, com 2 colunas. Cada coluna tem 1 botão, que ao clicar, abre um link, no caso, do Youtube.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
            android:text="DemonDies"
            android:onClick="demondies"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/demondies" />...
```

Aí no JAVA faço o resto:

```
 Button demondies,...
 demondies = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.demondies);

demondies.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCEWQoXe934RcJr04efPm9OQ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });...
```

Até aí blz, só que agora tá começando a ter muitos botões, e tá ficando meio difícil de continuar criando botão assim. Teria um jeito de criar botões dinamicamente, recuperando o nome e url do link do banco de dados ou algo parecido? 
Ia adicionar a imagem aqui pra ver como é o layout, mas ela fica muito grande.

***Edit***
O layout fica assim:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Can2o.jpg

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O uso de uma ListView não resolveria o problema?

Comment: posta a foto num site de hospedagem de fotos

Comment: Edit: postei a imagem.

Comment: Como fazer botões clicáveis num listview?

Comment: Você vai ter que fazer uma listView customizada. Basicamente, você terá um xml que representará um único item da lista e terá também uma classe adaptadora que terá de receber uma lista de Strings com os nomes dos botões e também será a responsável por vincular os dados dessa lista de Strings nos botões que aparecem nas telas. Aguarde que posto o código.

Comment: entendi, faço isso com um listview de imagens atualmente, se tiver como fazer com botões, ótimo

Comment: Recycler View...

Comment: Imagens voce usa ImageView no xml. Buttons é só usar Button no xml... É o mesmo princípio; só muda a aparencia do widget.

Comment: Mais fácil do que a ListView acredito que seja você usar o GridView. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: O que você quer é pegar vários dados (URL, nome, etc) e criar os botões automaticamente, correto? Tem sim, primeiramente precisa puxar os dados de algum lugar (sqlite, banco remoto, webservice, json, etc) e rodar um script para isso. Já vi isso uma vez. Vou ver se acho e posto. Mas para te adiantar, tem sim como fazer.

Comment: Essa é uma pergunta parecida que fiz, e ainda não testei: [Pegar valores de EditText gerados programaticamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243338/pegar-valores-de-edittext-gerados-programaticamente) ... Dá para tirar uma ideia creio eu.

Answer (score 0):

voce pode criar um layout para os botoes:
Arquivo `btn_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="90dp"
   android:layout_columnWeight="1"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
   android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
   android:text="DemonDies"
   android:onClick="demondies"
   android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
   android:id="@+id/demondies"
</Button>
```

Criar um adapter para esse button.
Arquivo `GridButtonsAdapter.java`:

```
public class GridButtonsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override 
    publc int getCount() {
        return list.size;
    }

    @Override 
    public String getItem(position: int) {
        return list[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(position: int) {
        return (long)position;
    }

    private Context mContext;
    GridButtonsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> btnsNames) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.list = btnsNames;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate o view personalizado
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Button itemLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.btn_layout, null);

        Button cellBtn = itemLayout.findViewById<View>(R.id.demondies);

        String name = list[position]

        cellBtn.setText(name)
        cellBtn.tag(name)
        return row
    }
}
```

depois, na sua activity principal voce monta o adapter

```
//...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    // criar o metodo para preencher a sua lista de urls para o itemclick
    ArrayList<String> urlList = pegaSuaListaDeUrlsDoSeuDatabase();
    // criar o metodo para preencher a sua lista de nomes do seu database
    // voce pode criar um metodo void e criar esses dois campos no escopo
    // da classe e preencher os dois campos num unico metodo void onde
    // voce pega os valores para os nomes e para as urls, assim, simplifica
    // e diminui o codigo
    ArrayList<String> btnsNamesList = pegaSuaListaDeNomesDoSeuDatabase();
    // monta o adapter para a sua GridView
    GridLayout gridbtns = findViewById(R.id.suagrid);
    GridButtonsAdapter mAdapter = new GridButtonsAdapter(this, btnsNamesList);
    // cria um listener para o onItemClick de cada button dentro do adapter
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = (arg0, arg1, position, id) -> {
        // aqui voce pega um determinado item da lista de urls
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(urlList.get(position));
        // e passa ela para o intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    };
    // passa o listener paa o click do adapter
    gridbtns.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
    // passa o adapter para a grid
    gridbtns.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

assim, voce vai conseguir criar seus botoes dinamicamente.
Logicamente, isso é apenas um exemplo.
Espero que te ajude