# Pegar valores de EditText gerados programaticamente

Tags: java, android

Tenho um APP, que `preencho a quantidade de jogadores` que terá o campeonato e clico num `botão` para criar o campeonato.
Esse botão joga para uma `activity` que pega a quantidade que foi setada e `gera N EditText` com um loop. Até aqui ok.

Depois que gerou esses `EditText`, eu preencho todos com os nomes, e preciso que quando eu clicar no `botão`, ele ir para outra `activity` e leve os `valores` dos `EditText`.

A `questão` é: como eu puxo os `valores` dos `EditText`, se são gerados programaticamente e preciso do `ID` para isso ??

Seria jogando-os em um array e depois consultando !?

Exemplo do que uso para gerar os `EditText` sem o loop por enquanto:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout ll;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setText("Jogador");
        ll.addView(et);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você já tem a quantidade de jogadores, primeiro crie um `ArrayList` de `EditText` e coloque-os no seu layout:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout ll;
    private ArrayList<EditText> listaEdt = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
        int qntdJogadores = b.getStringArray("quantidade");

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < qntdJogadores; i++) {
            listaEdt.add(new EditText(this));
            listaEdt.get(i).setText("Jogador " + i);
            ll.addView(listaEdt.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Depois faça o seguinte para pegar o valores e passar para a próxima `Activity`:

```
ArrayList<String> nomes = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < listaEdt.size(); i++) {
    nomes.add(listaEdt.get(i).getText().toString());
}

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayListExtra("NOMES_ARRAY_LIST", nomes);
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OutraActivity.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo você precisará armazenar todos seus EditText em uma View. Após você armazenar em uma view e depois ir contando seus filhos, você deverá utilizar o método getChild para conseguir pegar os filhos da View, e ir armazenando os valores dos filhos em um array:

```
final int childCount = viewLayout.getChildCount();
String[] str = new String[childCount];
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      EditText edt = viewLayout.getChildAt(i);
      childCount = edt.getText().toString();
}
```

Com isso você ira armazenar os valores que estão dentro dos EditText em um array de strings.

Para troca de dados entre activitys você irá precisar usar `Intent` irei te dar um pequeno exemplo para adapta-lo ao seu código.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OutraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SEU_TEXTO", str);
startActivity(intent);
```

E na outra activity você pode pegar o valor pela key `SEU_TEXTO`

```
String[] textos = getIntent().getStringArray("SEU_TEXTO");
```

Comment: Onde isso entraria no meu loop se não tenho ao certo a quantidade de EditTexts ?

Comment: Dessa forma quando você clicar no botão, você irá passar os valores de uma acitity para outra..

Comment: Entendi melhor oque você está falando...

Comment: Sim, mas eu tenho que fazer isso para uma quantidade de EditText variada... como sei quais os nomes ou ID ?

Comment: Reeditei minha resposta da uma olhada